# Jquery Validate - How validate input with default value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using Jquery Validate, as follows:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="count_1" name="count_1" value="0011">
```

The input field has a default value (value = "0011"); I need to validate an exact number of 20 digits (including default):

If you enter fewer digits, say 2, 16, 19 or any number less than 20 digits must show a error ("Please enter 20 digits"); but if you return to the default values should not show any error.

Does anybody know how do it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `minlength` rule?  If _"you're using"_ jQuery Validate, then show us your code.  Where is your call to the `.validate()` method?   Why do you have a `value` set inline when you need the user to enter their own data?

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> If you enter fewer digits, say 2, 16, 19 or any number less than 20
>   digits must show a error ("Please enter 20 digits"); but if you return
>   to the default values should not show any error.

To prevent your "default" value from messing up your validation, use `placeholder` instead of `value` to set this "default"...

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="count_1" name="count_1" placeholder="0011">
```

---

Use the `minlength` rule to mandate 20 characters...

```
$('#yourform').validate({
    // your other options,
    rules: {
        count_1: {
            minlength: 20
        }
    },
    messages: {
        count_1: {
            minlength: "Please enter {0} digits"
        }
    }
});
```

In the custom message, the `{0}` is *automatically* replaced with the `minlength` parameter of `20`.